# API with encrypted database and key management

Tags: python, jwt, fastapi

My web app in a nutshell: password manager with FastAPI.

1. db table users storing username and MasterPassword
2. db table services storing a list of websites with their corresponding credentials (login/password)

The services table is encrypted and decrypted with the MasterPassword (under the hood, a key is derived from the MasterPassword) of the User owner on the fly each time I need access to them. For the moment, the db is just stored in a file (w/ TinyDB).
A working class named 'Services' have been created for handling those operations.

Example of code:

```
u = User(username, masterpassword)
s = Services(u)
s.decrypt()
... # do some things with s
s.encrypt()
```

Now I am building an API to access the services.
Login is easy to implement, I create a User instance which requires a username and a MasterPassword, look for it in the db with the hashed MasterPassword and I even can return a JWT to the client.

But now here is the problem, I can access some restricted resources with the JWT (some specific pages or else)  but I cannot encrypt/decrypt the database on the fly since there is no way to transport the MasterPassword in the JWT (and I don't want to obviously) or to keep it in memory on the server side (I could for sure but it doesn't sound like something secure).

What I could do for sure is not to use a JWT, but just returning the services table once after the login, do whatever I want on the client side (like modifying some credentials, add some entries, remove some, so on and so forth) and then request and update to the API by again providing the MasterPassword. But it sounds not convenient as well.

I have found this: https://github.com/padamupreti/password-manager-api
However there is a unique key to decrypt all the tables (whatever the owner) out of the database.
I don't want that, because ultimately, any user could export the services table files and use it on his own.

So, what kind of architecture should I use?

Comment: The server should _not_ be able to decrypt the row from the services table at all; only the client should be able to do that. The "What I could do for sure .." section is what password managers should do, so that even if the database leaks, your passwords are still safe because the attacker don't have access to the key used to decrypt the database (which never left the client).

Comment: Storing secrets is a huge responsibility, the basic _idea_ of a password manager is something you don't really want to undertake if you can avoid it. This needs to be designed with the _least responsibility_ principle in mind. The server _must not_ be able to know the plaintext passwords at all. The server wants to be as dumb as possible. The real secret (the master password) must not leave the user's head, or at least stay on the client. You want to do all en-/decryption on the client, and let the server store meaningless encrypted blobs only.